# Assigning output of a twig function to a twig variable

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I have the twig/assetic code below:

```
{% if post.media %}
    {% image '@ApplicationMyBundle/Resources/images/AjaxLoader-298x179.gif' output='/images/AjaxLoader-298x179.gif' %}
        <img src="{{ asset_url }}" data-src="{% path post.media, 'news_size_4' %}" />
    {% endimage %}
{% endif %}
```

The real image path is in `{% path post.media, 'news_size_4' %}`, I need to get this output in to a variable so i can use it elsewhere. {{ asset_url }} is no good as that only gives me the ajaxloader image.

Is there anyway this can be done?

Comment: The `{% path %}` tag is an official assetic tag?

Comment: I have never tested but have you tried `{% set imgPath = path post.media, 'news_size_4' %}` ? and then `data-src={{imgPath}}`

Comment: @hakim No Ive tried that,  it doesn't work unfortunately,  martin I'm yet to get confirmation on that but we do use it and it does work, as far as I'm aware we haven't created any custom functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Hakim in a comment, you can use the [set Twig tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html).

Define the variable:

```
{% set myPath %}
    {% path post.media, 'news_size_4' %}
{% endset %}
```

Display this variable:

```
{{ myPath }}
```

Comment: Please note it's not the twig path function but the assetic version and using the set tag as the main tag means path doesn't get picked up.

Comment: @Kevin I updated my answer. If the variable is not available outside of the `{% image`, I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: This looks interesting and I haven't tried this.  The var is available outside the image tag. I'll give this a go monday morning. If this works you get the points!!